# How to update a textbox in asp.net gridview dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, textbox

I have two columns in gridview.
One is textbox and the other is also a textbox.

If one textbox text changed , i need to perform some calculation and again need to 
fill automatically the second textbox.

(e.g) Ifi enter 10 in 1st textbox, i need to perform some calculation and again the result 
of that manipulation needs to shown in the textbox automatically once the text is entered 
in the first textbox.

I am not getting a way to achieve this..

please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the `Leave` Event of the first TextBox `TextBox1`.

Try This:

```
textBox1.Leave += new System.EventHandler(textBox1_Leave);
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      //Do calculations on TextBox1 value to display the result on TextBox2
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Again i need to update other textbox value in the same row . how to achieve that ?